# Ban IPs that Brute force Windows 10 Remote RDP

Tags: windows-10, security, remote-desktop

How many attempts does one need before Windows 10 ban's an IP addresses? I want to secure my Windows 10 RDP computer from brute force attempts.

Comment: Windows 10 does not ban an IP address if invalid RDP attempts are made, if you want, you will need third-party software and/or hardware to handle that case.

Comment: This belongs on>>>>https://security.stackexchange.com/